# Make a new array of values from 2d array properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array set up with `Object` for some specified length. the structure of the array of objects is such as:

```
{
   color
   text
   id
   vids {
      vidfile
      id
   }
   {
      vidfile
      id
   }
}
{
   color
   text
....
```

and so on. notice that each `object` has an `id` and each `vid` object inside has an `id` as well. The number of `object`s can change as well as the number of `vids`. I need a way to map a new array of objects with the structure {id, scroll_top} of each id, both from `object` and `vids`, in the old array.

I have something along the lines of

```
let new_array = []

for (let object of old_array) {
    new_array.push({id: object.id, scroll_top: document.getElementById(object.id).offsetTop})
    for (let vid of object.vids) {
      new_array.push({id: vid.id, scroll_top: document.getElementById(vid.id).offsetTop})
    }
  }
```

However I am getting TypeErrors of `document.getElementById(...) is null`

any pointers?

Comment: For the `document.getElementById` returning null, it means there are no elements in the document with an id attribute with that value. Also, arrays don't work the way you're thinking. You want objects, like `let obj = {}; obj[object.id] = document.getElementById(object.id).offsetTop;` if you want to reference entries by name like what you're showing.

Comment: my issue with the `null` problem is that hardcoding the same line without the referenced `object.id` shows just fine, and `console.log` shows the `object.id` is storing properly